# Mixin in a trait parameterized with Enumeration into Enumeration

Tags: scala, enumeration

I'm trying to add a function `apply` to my `Enumeration`s. I want to map enumerated values to functions and later on use it like this:

```
Action(DO_THIS, "Arg string")
```

which should print it's value. I have multiple enum classes and I'm trying to implement this functionality once via a trait mixin. So far I've failed to make compiler happy. I have this code that does not compile:

```
trait EnumFunc [EnumType <: Enumeration] {
  protected def funcMappings: Map[EnumType#Value, Function1[String, Unit]]

  def apply(enum: EnumType#Value, arg: String): Unit =
    funcMappings.getOrElse(enum, (arg: String) => ())(arg)
}


trait Action extends Enumeration with EnumFunc[Action] {
  type Action = Value

  val DO_THIS, DO_THAT = Value

  override val funcMappings: Map[Action, Function1[String, Unit]] =
    Map(DO_THIS -> ((arg: String) => println(arg)))
}

object Action extends Action
```

The compiler produces this error:

```
error: overriding method funcMappings in trait EnumFunc of type => Map[Action#Value,String => Unit];
 value funcMappings has incompatible type
         override val funcMappings: Map[Action, Function1[String, Unit]] =
```

I can't figure out exactly what the problem is. Could someone please explain if it's possible to achieve this at all and why this does not compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Value` inside of `Action` and `EnumType#Value` are not quite the same. `Value` inside of `Action` is a path-dependent type, it can only refer to instances of `Values` that have `this` as their parent, i.e. `Value` is a synonym for `this.Value`. `EnumType#Value` is a type projection, it can refer to any value from an instance of `EnumType`, and doesn't care what it's parent is. So the declaration of `funcMappings` and `apply` in `Action` are in fact being given stricter parameter types, which is not type-safe.

However, the type parameter on `EnumType` isn't actually needed, if you extend `Enumeration` you can use `Value` directly:

```
trait EnumFunc extends Enumeration {
  protected def funcMappings: Map[Value, Function1[String, Unit]]

  def apply(enum: Value, arg: String): Unit =
    funcMappings.getOrElse(enum, (arg: String) => ())(arg)
}
```

and then it will work. However, this is just one of the many examples of how Scala's `Enumeration` is an abomination. Once you know you want to add methods to the individual elements, it's much better to use a hierarchy of case classes/objects:

```
abstract class Doers {
  def apply(s: String): Unit
}
case object DoThis extends Doers {
  def apply(s: String): Unit = println(s)
}
case object DoThat extends Doers {
  def apply(s: String): Unit = ???
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, indeed Enumeration is a pain, but I have to use it because a third party library I use takes Enumeration values. I was too restrictive with the type, but as far as I understand your solution works because of type erasure where all instances of Value become the same, they don't "remember" enclosing class type.

Comment: I realized my explanation of why your code didn't work was incorrect, I've edited my answer. `Enumeration` actually relies on path-dependent types, so it should be safe even with type erasure.